# clustering? classifications? multiple regressions?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, clustering

[image]

what I wanna do is extract some information from this graph.
little bit about this data is the x is the amount of stuffs that ppl buy and y is how much they pay. and the colors show the different genre of stuff.

I thought use k-means to cluster theses data by genre using  x and y but I'm not sure.
Multiple regression might work as well but first I need you guys to tell your thoughts.

pls tell me any ideas about this graph

Comment: Are you literally asking about scraping this image for information or are you asking about how to analyze the data represented by the image?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do.

1. Regression: predict average price *or* amount given that you know the kind and the other value.
2. Classification: given the price *and* amount, predict the type.
3. Clustering: forget that you already know the kind, and try to rediscover it.

Clearly, as you already have the colors, 3 does not make much sense. But I doubt that either 1 or 2 is particularly interesting on this data either. Looks very much fake data anyway. But you'd need many more attributes to find any interesting learning task beyond computing the average price/quantity for each genre.